# how do i know which port that client using?

Tags: port-forwarding

I have server on windows, and there is client want to connect to my server using a specific port, 
how do i know which port that client use, and which port do we need to port forward on windows?
please suggest me some freeware Windows service (application)

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

The client uses any port they like to connect - it is randomised and they dont have a control over it. You have to forward the specific port the server uses. That depends on what your server is - a http/web server forwards 80 and 443 - an FTP forwards 21 (at the least) - it depends what port your server listens on. More information on the specific server you want to set up would help suggest the port or port range to forward.

The client port is randomised by their for NAT but does not matter - they still connect to your IP on the port that you forward for your server

Comment: The client port is largely randomised and usually chosen by the router - *it does not matter*. The client's port is of no use to you - whatever port they choose to use still goes to you on your server port

Comment: I just wanna know if Is there anyway to know which port that client use?

Comment: You cannot - this is *randomised* by their router.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port